# VUE: the whole page disappeared, only showing "Proxy error..."

Tags: vue.js

When I first entered this route it was normal, but when I refreshed the whole page disappeared, only showing "Proxy error: Could not proxy request ... from ... to ...",The same routing settings only appear on this page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9mt4.png)

Comment: some code might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may find the problem now,my proxy '/a' and routing address '/index/a' are duplicated.After I modify the route name, I can refresh it and access it normally

Answer (score 0):

Check your back end server it's running or not. 
If it is running change your proxy to

```
"proxy": {
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://[::1]:8080"
    }
}
```

or change localhost:PROXY_PORT to 127.0.0.1:PROXY_PORT this might work for you

Comment: My agent is normal, just like your description. Other pages are written in the same way, and other pages are normal. Only after this refresh is inaccessible

Comment: I may find the problem now,my proxy '/a' and routing address '/index/a' are duplicated,After I modify the route name, I can refresh it and access it normally